# Installing mongo module for php

Tags: mongodb, pecl

I'm trying to install mongo module for php, almost all installation guides I found online are using pecl, when I try: `sudo /usr/local/pear/bin/pecl install mongo`

I'm getting this error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongo"
install failed
```

Have I configured pecl wrong or is it discontinued?

Answer (score 5):

Could you paste the output of

```
pecl config-show
pecl version
```

I can't really imagine how this could be possible?
Maybe running very old pear (since before the package format change (2008 or earlier even). Can you actually install any pecl extension?

In any case, you can install the extension by downloading it first, and then installing it using the local archive:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo
pecl install mongo-*.tgz
```